# Servlet threw exception "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: java, servlets

in my servlet im writing the following statement to load the ontology file

```
File fileBase = new File("src/java/ontology/ontology.owl");
SimpleIRIMapper iriMapper =  new SimpleIRIMapper(IRI.create("src/java/ontology/AOA.owl"),
            IRI.create(fileBase));
```

but when i run the project i got the following exception

> org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyInputSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\java\ontology\ontology.owl (The system cannot find the path specified)

how can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: It has to be a path relative to the servlet url pattern.

Answer (score 0):

provide the absolute path / place the file in class path as 
`File fileBase = new File("ontology.owl");`